# Qpython in Android

Tags: android, python, qpython

I wanted to write python code in my local computer and transfer it to Android device to execute the codes in mobile or Tablet.

Is it possible to transfer? If yes, in which location do I need to transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `QPython` in `Programs` I see `/storages/emulated/0/com.hipipal/qpyplus/scripts/`

Comment: Do I need to transfer to Android device?

Comment: Unable to find. I used MTP. It doesn't show qpython.

Comment: Thanks , it worked. When I try to create text file . I get an IOError 30. How to solve that. Do I need root acess to create and write file